# How to add a volume from a diferent server to my docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm setting to set up a dokcer-compose file, and want to access a docker volume which is on another server. How do I specify that external volume in my docker-compose file?

I've tried using the driver_opts in my docker-compose file but without luck. I always get this error:

> ERROR: for api  Cannot start service api: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/data-api-media': error while mounting volume with options: type='' device='remote-path' o='addr=***.***.***.***,rw': no such device

And with external I get:

> Volume data-api-media declared as external, but could not be found. Please create the volume manually using `docker volume create --name=data-api-media` and try again.

version: '3.4'
services:
  api:
    build: .
    entrypoint: 
      - ./docker-entrypoint.sh
    volumes:
      - data-api-media:/usr/src/app/media/
    ports:
      - "1095:1095"
volumes:
  data-api-media:
    driver_opts:
      o: "addr=***.***.***.***,rw"
      device: remote-path

I expect to mount the external docker volume from a different server to my docker-compose service and access the files in it.

Comment: How would you access this data if Docker weren't involved?  If it was all on the same host?

Comment: If it was on the same host, using external: true would do the trick

Comment: Sorry I did not see the part where you said that docker wasn't involved. If it was on the same host I would have access to the folder so no problem there, or what do you mean? @DavidMaze

Comment: If it's an NFS share or something else you could **mount**(8), there's an extended Docker volume syntax that can do it, but on its own Docker on host A doesn't have a way to access a Docker volume on host B.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks, I'll try that instead. I really thought that I could solve it with a Docker volume.

Answer (score 2):

You can create [docker volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) through [vieux/sshfs](https://github.com/vieux/docker-volume-sshfs) plugin at your host and map to another host.

## Use a volume driver

When you create a volume using docker volume create, or when you start a container which uses a not-yet-created volume, you can specify a volume driver. The following examples use the vieux/sshfs volume driver, first when creating a standalone volume, and then when starting a container which creates a new volume.

### Initial set-up

This example assumes that you have two nodes, the first of which is a Docker host and can connect to the second using SSH.

On the Docker host, install the vieux/sshfs plugin:

```
$ docker plugin install --grant-all-permissions vieux/sshfs
```

Create a volume using a volume driver
This example specifies a SSH password, but if the two hosts have shared keys configured, you can omit the password. Each volume driver may have zero or more configurable options, each of which is specified using an -o flag.

```
$ docker volume create --driver vieux/sshfs \
  -o sshcmd=test@node2:/home/test \
  -o password=testpassword \
  sshvolume
```

### docker-compose setup

```
volumes:
  - type: volume
    driver: vieux/sshfs
    source: sshvolume
    target: /target
```